# How to solve "Task could not find al.exe using the SdkToolPath" error while creating .NET Core API?

Tags: c#, api, .net-core

i want to add a resource file to my application. The problem is when i'm trying to build my solution, i get an error MSB3086 with the description "Task could not find "al.exe" using the SdkTollsPath "" or registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\NETFXSDK\4.7.2\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x86". Make sure the SdkToolsPath is set and the tool exists in the correct processor specific location under the SdkTollsPath and that the Microsoft Windows SDK is installed." The problem occurs only when i'm trying to name my resource file including culture info as shown below:

[image]

If i changed a name to UsersController.resx everything compiles, but i cannot get any value from the resource file. Here is snippet responsible for the configuration from my Startup class:

```
services.AddLocalization(opts => { opts.ResourcesPath = "Tabler.WebApi/Resources"; }); //ConfigureServices

app.UseRequestLocalization(options => //Configure method
{
     IList<CultureInfo> supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
     {
          new CultureInfo("en-US"),
     };

     options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US");
     options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
     options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
});
```

Here I inject IStringLocalizer (I cannot retrieve data from it, if i build an application with the "UsersController.resx" file name):

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{

    private readonly IUserService _userService;
    private readonly ITokenGenerator _tokenGenerator;
    private readonly IStringLocalizer<UsersController> _stringLocalizer;

    public UsersController(IUserService userService, ITokenGenerator tokenGenerator, IStringLocalizer<UsersController> stringLocalizer) : base()
    {

        this._userService = userService;
        this._tokenGenerator = tokenGenerator;
        this._stringLocalizer = stringLocalizer;

    }
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Broken VS install, you'll need to spin the repair/re-install wheel of fortune.